# Не отображается NavigationDraver в activity с ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Прошелся по этому [туториалу](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/), проект запускается, но при нажатии на копку `NavigationDrawer` не появляется, но если убрать с `acivity` `ViewPager` то все работает, как можно совместить `ViewPager` и `NavigationDrawer` , вот код в моем проекте:

```
public class MainActivity extends CalingPlatform {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

//ViewPager and TabLayout
private CustomViewPagerH viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private TextView tvTitle;

//NavigationDrawer
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private CustomDrawerAdapter drawerAdapter;

private List<DrawerItem> dataList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init ViewPager with TabLayout
    viewPager = (CustomViewPagerH) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

    //init NavigationDrawer
    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, GravityCompat.END);

    // Add Drawer Item to dataList
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message",R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video",R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups",R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help",R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    drawerAdapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item, dataList);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "onDrawerClosed" );
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to

            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "onDrawerOpened" );
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            int i = 0;
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SelectItem(0);
    }


    //тут наполняються страници во ViewPager
    //...

}


public void SelectItem(int possition) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Selected item: " + possition);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
    setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        SelectItem(position);

    }
}
```

}

и **main_activity.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.platformcaling.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
             this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
             languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
             The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
             the container. A solid background is used for contrast
             with the content view. -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#ffff"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.platformcaling.CustomViewPagerH
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/appBar_layout"
        >
    </com.platformcaling.CustomViewPagerH>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorTabs"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо в примере что-то не так. Попробуйте вручную открыть дровер так:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    //if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        //return true;
    //}
    if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home) {
         mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Вы неправильно составили разметку. У вас должен быть

1. DrawerLayout корневым элементом
2. У него должно быть всего 2 потомка - контент и левое меню
3. Именно в контейнер для контента поместите всю вашу остальную разметку.

Comment: Вы правы, у меня еще в разметке был ViewPager, я хотел убрать лишний код что бы оставить только нужное, но щас убрал ViewPager с проекта и все заработало. Я щас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. поправил верстку , все заработало.